# Nivo Slider: control nav thumb loose cursor pointer property after change image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, carousel, nivo-slider

I'm stuck with this. Hope you can helpme. I'm adapting Nivo Slider for a site (I must use jquery 1.5.1). Everything is fine but the issue now is that when the image change the control nav thumbs loose its cursor pointer property. I mean, the click only works the first time the slide runs but when the image change the controls in the thumbs doesn't allow to make click.

Here you can see the slider:
http://www.sixplus1.com.mx/stackoverflow/carrusel_stack.html

The nivo slider Script:
http://www.sixplus1.com.mx/stackoverflow/js/jquery_kfu.nivo.slider.pack.js.js

I've been diging on the script to find a reason, around line 175 to 201, specifically on line 193 is the function that add the class to the thumbnails nav controller,

```
`$('.nivo-controlNav a:eq('+vars.currentSlide+')',slider).addClass('active');
$('.nivo-controlNav a',slider).live('click',function(){
if(vars.running)return false;
if($(this).hasClass('active'))return false;
clearInterval(timer);
timer='';]`
```

but I can't find anything that helps. I set in all the states of the thumb (on the css) the "cursor:pointer" property. And it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is because your `.nivo-slice` goes over your `.nivo-controlNav` so when you hover it, you're actually going on top of the slice and not the `.nivo-controlNav`.

To solve this, by looking at your code, you only need to add a `z-index`

```
.nivo-controlNav {
 z-index:10;
}
```

In your case, you need a z-index higher than 5 because `.nivo-slice` has a z-index of 5.

Comment: I would rock even more if you upvoted and marked this as the answer! :)